# Matplotlib export text as line elements in Python

Tags: python, text, vector, matplotlib, export

I have to build some rudimentary CAD Tool in Python based on `matplotlib` for handling the display of the content.
After all the parts have been put together, the whole layout shall be exported as line elements (basically just tuples of the start / end coordinates of the lines, e.g. [x1,y1,x2,y2]) and just points.

So far I have all the basic gemoetric stuff implemented, but I cannot figure out how to implement text properly. To be able to use different fonts etc. I want to use the text capabilities of matplotlib, but I can't find a way to export the text properly from matplotlib.

Is there a way to get a vectorized output right away? Or at least an array of the plotted text?

Comment: Can you save the figure/plot from `matplotlib` to a pdf file, and then use another program to convert the pdf to some type of cad file? Maybe this would help with that: http://blog.rubypdf.com/2009/11/18/convert-pdf-to-dxf-with-free-open-source-software-pstoedit-and-ghostscript/

Comment: @shockburner No, using 2 extra tools is not really an option, since the programm shall be moved around a lot portably, so I want to keep the number of dependencies down to a minimum. I might come back to this if nothing else works, but for now I still hope for something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of struggling, I found a way to get the outline of the text: https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py , more precisely the example https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py/blob/master/examples/glyph-vector.py

If you just want to get the outline as an vector array, you can delete everything after line 78 and do this:

```
path = Path(VERTS, CODES)
outline = path.to_polygons()
```

This will give you an array of polygons, and each polygon is again an array of points (x,y) of the polygon.

Though it was some trouble to get freetype running on windows and I still have not figured out how to make it portable, I think I will stick with this solution, because it is fast, reliable and allows one to use all the nice system fonts.